# I would like to receive a message notification (popup style) of the incoming message while I am using the other admin account

Tags: c#, windows

I set up 2 administrative accounts on my computer and I open one chat executable on one; the chat application can be whatever (self-made systems, skype, yahoo...). I would like to receive a message notification (popup style) of the coming message sent into it while I am using the other admin account.

Details: 2 accounts A and B, both are logged on and switched back and forth. Chat application is running on account A and I log in to it. I then select switch user from System Start menu and pick account B to log on. Someone, maybe a friend sends me a message via chat system in account A. Now I would want to see a system notification message of the message from my friend.

Comment: Just open up another chat window in the second computer account.

Comment: Windows Live (MSN) Messenger, GTalk, and possibly other instant messaging apps allow you be logged in to multiple places with the same account. Messages sent to that account will "fan out" and be received by all clients. In other words, log into Messenger/Gtalk on both admin accounts and you won't ever miss a message.  Is that what you want?  Or are you trying to do something else?  Why C#?

Comment: Thanks, but no that is not what I want, I don't want to open a new chat instance on account B, I would want some process I will create to notify me about the message in the account A. I guess I've worked often with C# lately so I'll create this application in C#.

Answer (score 0):

What I userstand from your application, you have server or receiver in each client then you have some solution to solve this problem:

First of all you can add a windows service to your application and it can manage your receive message to show in witch account. You can get user information by `UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User` and in recieve message event you notify logon user. note that windows service must show the notification.

In second solution if locked user processes work in lock mode (I think it works) you manage receive message to notify all users in that computer or logon user. in this case you must create small program for notification and run it with `Process.start(ProcessStartInfo)` (you can use it in case 1 too).

good luck.